# Badge isn't a function

Tags: flutter, dart

I've problem that says badge isn't a function and can't read it. And the second issue says, "The name 'Badge' is defined in the libraries". can u help me guys?

```
Widget _buildIconNotified() {
    return Badge(
      badgeColor: AppColor.actionColor,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
      position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: -7, end: 0),
      badgeContent: Text('', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child: _buildIcon(),
    );
  }
```

i've tried to remove badges dependency from pubspec.lock. but nothing changed

Answer (score 5):

If you check the documentation of the package at https://pub.dev/packages/badges it says:

> Attention! In Flutter 3.7 the Badge widget was introduced in the
> Material library, so to escape the ambiguous imports you need to
> import the package like this:
>
> ```
> import 'package:badges/badges.dart' as badges;
> ```

And then use it as `badges.Badge`, like this for example

```
badges.Badge(
  badgeContent: Text('3'),
  child: Icon(Icons.settings),
)
```